# AWK with space in new lines

Tags: awk

I have a file in which the first column is empty in alternate rows, It is something like below

```
Group Name          Node Name    Suspended    State
----------          ---------    ---------    -----
abc                 sales1          No         Online
                    sales2          No         Online

abc2                sales2          No          Online
                    sales1          No          Online

xyz                 sales1          No          Online
                    sales4          No          Online

xyz                 sales5          No          Offline
                    sales2          No          Online
```

I just want the first column replicated for next like so the output of `awk '{ print $1 }'` is something like below

```
abc
abc

abc2
abc2

xyz
xyz

xyz
xyz
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: On top of that, there is a wide variety on how we can interpret your question: **(1)** how is a column defined **(2)** can spaces appear in the value of column 1 **(3)** does column 1 always start at the first character, or is an accidental white space possible. If we want to give you a robust answer, we have to know a description of the data table, or how the table is formed (which command is used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR<=2{next} !/^ /{print $1;val=$1;next} NF{print val}' Input_file
```

OR a non-one liner form of solution is:

```
awk '
FNR<=2{
  next
}
!/^ /{
  print $1
  val=$1
  next
}
NF{
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation here.

```
awk '          ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR<=2{        ##Checking condition if FNR lesser than or equal to 2 then simply skip all further statements from here.
  next         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!/^ /{         ##Checking condition if a line does not start from space then do following.
  print $1     ##Printing 1st field of line here.
  val=$1       ##Creating variable val whose value is $1 of current line.
  next         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
NF{            ##Checking condition if a line is NOT NULL then do following.
  print val    ##Printing variable val here.
}
' Input_file   ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: That can be reduced to just `awk '!/^ /{val=$1} NR>2{print val}' file`